# How to reset selects inside an array without v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js

### Problem

I need to reset all `select`s inside an array that has no `v-model`s within Vue.js.

#### Template

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(element, index) in elements">
    <select @input="setElement(index, $event.target.value)">
      <option v-for="option in options" :value="option">{{option}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <button @click="addElement">
    Set three elements
  </button>
</div>
```

#### Script

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      options: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
      elements: [{
        element: ''
      }, {
        element: ''
      }]
    }
  },

  methods: {
    addElement() {
        this.elements = []
        this.elements.push({
          element: ''
        })
        this.elements.push({
          element: ''
        })
        this.elements.push({
          element: ''
        })
      },

      setElement(index, el) {
        let element = {
          element: el
        }

        this.$set(this.elements, index, element)
      }
  }
})
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/jqb99tks/4/

### Wish

When the length of `elements` change (e. g. a reset), the `select`s should be reset.

### Approach

I can iterate through all HTML `select`s and manually reset them but that feels like a hacked solution.

Comment: What you are trying to do ?

Comment: If you don't tie the values to your viewmodel, you are saying the selected value doesn't matter to your application. But clearly it does. So create some data items and use `v-model`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it happens it because Vue tries to reuse HTML and prevent expensive rerender it it thinks it's possible to do so. In your case it chooses not to rerender select boxes. To tell framework that you want HTML to be rerendered (like in your case to reset selected value) you just need to use unique key prop which is different from previous rendered value:

```
<div v-for="(element, index) in elements">
  <select :key="index + elements.length" @input="setElement(index, $event.target.value)">
    <option v-for="option in options" :value="option">{{option}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Note, that I added `:key="index + elements.length"`. `elements.length` is there to make key depend on length of `elements`, `index` alone is not enough as it will be the same, i.e. 0, 1, etc.

Also note, that for it to work you need to revise `setElement` method as it's doing something weird at the moment, `this.$set(this.elements, index, element)` is a problem. Change it to something like this:

```
setElement(index, value) {
  this.$set(this.elements[index], 'element', value)
}
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/jqb99tks/6/

Comment: Very clever solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This maybe better for you.
[v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/index.html#v-model) can be used for 'select'.

https://jsfiddle.net/loocao/jqb99tks/8/

```
<div v-for="(element, index) in elements">
  <select v-model="element.element">
    <option v-for="option in options" :value="option" :selected="element.element === option">{{option}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

methods:

```
addElement() {
    // first select
    this.elements.splice(0,1,{element: ''})
    // add one
    this.elements.push({element: 'a'})
}
```